# Complex numbers and for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, complex-numbers

I need to make a function that tests if a complex number, c is in the Mandelbrot set which is defined as z<sub>n+1</sub> = z<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup> + c. The values of n are in subscript if that was confusing. The function accepts variables c (some complex number of the form 0 + 0j) and n (number of iterations). To see if c is in the set, I need to test z = z**2 + c > 2. If > 2 I need to return false. Now I know that with c = 0 + 0j and n = 25 I should get True. But I can only get true with very small values of n. What do I need to do differently.

```
def inMSet(c,n):
    for x in range(0, n):
        z = n**2 + c
        if abs(z) > 2:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Comment: What programming language ??? Please tag responsibly.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but the `for` loop doesn't seem to be doing anything. Should you have `z = x**2 + c` instead?

Comment: So what exactly do I need to do with n in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition has an [iterative formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set#Formal_definition), starting with `z=0`.

```
def inMSet(c,n):
    z = 0
    for x in range(0, n):
        z = z**2 + c
        if abs(z) > 2:
            return False
    return True 

>>> inMSet(0+0j,25)
True
```

Comment: You sir, are a god among men. A benevolent deity bestowing the best of fortune to all. Let your will be done and your name be praised.